# What does work mean as a concept and not as a mathematical equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, definition

I know that work = Force times displacement or the dot product of the force and the displacement. But what does work mean in the physical world?

Just like we know that in the physical world, density is the compactness of a substance and we can deduce that via the formula of density which is the amount of mass occupying per unit volume, what does work mean then in the physical world?

I thought of the idea that work is a multiple of force by displacement s. But what does that mean in the physical world?

Answer (score 4):

You can think of work as the change in energy produced by a force. If a force does positive work on an object, then the object will gain energy. If a force does negative work on an object then the object will lose energy. Note I am just talking about a single force. When multiple forces are at play then the net force is what matters when considering if the object will gain or lose energy.

This is why forces perpendicular to an object in motion can only change the direction the object is moving in. The work done must be 0, so that no energy is added or taken away. A direction change does not change the object's speed, and therefore the energy has not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Work means that the barge owner pays the tugboat owner, in return
for being moved.   Without the concept of work, many
exchanges involving force and distance would be
much less comprehensible.

Work also explains to the tugbboat owner why the vessel's fuel
consumption goes up during times that the tow cable is under
strain.